# How to call Transaction.update using strongly typed UpdateData type

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore

Consider the method [`update(documentRef, dataOrField, …preconditionOrValues) → {Transaction}`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Transaction.html#update).

I need to be able to pass multiple pairs of (FieldPath, Value) because I need to update a few fields at once.  One can write something like this:

```
txn.update(docRef,
  'field1', value1,
  'field2', value2
);
```

Typescript offers the [UpdateData](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/blob/c89546f5ae83da3845076aeeffcda75f9b208f5c/types/firestore.d.ts#L35) type:

```
  /**
   * Update data (for use with `DocumentReference.update()`) consists of field
   * paths (e.g. 'foo' or 'foo.baz') mapped to values. Fields that contain dots
   * reference nested fields within the document.
   */
  export type UpdateData = {[fieldPath: string]: any};
```

and the [updateData method signature](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/blob/c89546f5ae83da3845076aeeffcda75f9b208f5c/types/firestore.d.ts#L378) is declared as:

```
    /**
     * Updates fields in the document referred to by the provided
     * `DocumentReference`. The update will fail if applied to a document that
     * does not exist.
     *
     * Nested fields can be updated by providing dot-separated field path
     * strings.
     *
     * @param documentRef A reference to the document to be updated.
     * @param data An object containing the fields and values with which to
     * update the document.
     * @param precondition A Precondition to enforce on this update.
     * @return This `Transaction` instance. Used for chaining method calls.
     */
    update(documentRef: DocumentReference<any>, data: UpdateData,
           precondition?: Precondition): Transaction;
```

Now, imagine that I have a bunch of field updates, like:

```
  const fieldUpdates: FirebaseFirestore.UpdateData[] = [
    { ['field1']: value1 },
    { ['field2']: value2 },
  ];
```

**How can I pass this to the `update` method?**  The following:

```
txn.update(docRef, ...fieldUpdates);
```

fails with:

```
Expected at least 2 arguments, but got 1 or more.ts(2557)
firestore.d.ts(378, 49): An argument for 'data' was not provided.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass a single object with the names and values of the fields to update.

```
txn.update(docRef, {
    field1: value1,
    field2: value2
})
```

In TypeScript, `{[fieldPath: string]: any}` means "an object with properties that must be strings, and their values can be anything".  In this case, they keys are the paths of the fields to update.

Comment: I need to emphasize that my `fieldUpdates` is actually a _dynamic list_ of updates.  In other words, I am not really passing a constant structure as you have described.

Comment: Then build your update object dynamically.  The API doesn't care how you make it. What you see here and in the docs is for simplicity, to illustrate how the APIs work.

Comment: I just got that!  And now I have it working.  Thank you for clarifying.